# How to simplify the code that filters out invalid characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that needs to be simplified, but i'm i can't get it right.

```py
if isinstance(texts, list):
    texts = list(filter(('/').__ne__, texts))
    texts = list(filter(('').__ne__, texts))
    texts = list(filter(('\\').__ne__, texts))
```

Main goal is to get rid of `__ne__` and make it a bit better readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
texts = [t for t in texts if t not in {'/', '', '\\'}]
```